# Can i compare WeakReference variables in java?

Tags: java, hashmap, weak-references

I have a `HashMap<MyClass,ArrayList<WeakReference<MyObject>>>` variable.

Eventhough weakrefences are cleaned from the hashmap, i also want to be able to manually remove "MyObject" from HashMap. This is a central listener object.

When i add items to the arraylist that is linked to the main hashmap key's value, i use `.add(new WeakReference<MyObject>(owner))`

When i want to remove "self" from an external place, i send "owner" as the parameter which is the real object. So how can i remove this object manually from my hashmap? Can i query with a new WeakReference generated from the incoming owner parameter? Will the old `"new WeakReference<MyObject>(owner)"` and the new `"new WeakReference<MyObject>(owner)"` be equal? So i could remove it from the hashmap.

Comment: what is the key that is used to store the weak references? Use the same key to remove the weak reference instance from the map.

Comment: He is not calling `add` on the map but on the `List`.

Comment: @NarendraPathai key is an enum which defines the type of listener. I can't remove the main key. i have to remove the listener from ArrayList. So assume that there are many keys like "A_CHANGED, B_CHANGED". A_CHANGED can have unlimited number of different objects those listening to A_CHANGED event. So i can't remove all objects from A_CHANGED.

Answer (score 7):

> Will the old "new WeakReference(owner)" and the new "new
>   WeakReference(owner)" be equal?

**No they will not be equal.** both are different objects and `equals` method is not overridden in Weak Reference. So it by default checks whether both the references are equal and they are not.

Suggestion:

```
Map<MyClass,Map<String,WeakReference<MyObject>>>
```

you can change the `list` to a `map` and use some **ID** kind of thing in object as the **key for weak reference.** And when the owner calls, use the ID of that object to remove the weak reference.

Comment: So, i have to return the created WeakReference(owner) to owner and owner will keep it's WeakReference?

Comment: Being equal and being the same is different. new String("foo") is equal to new String ("foo"), although they're different objects.

Comment: @JBNizet yes my bad. I edited the post to reflect the changes. Thanks.

Comment: IMO using id as key to store the weak reference would be much better than passing the WeakReference to the caller.

Answer (score 6):

No, because neither `WeakReference` nor its parent `Reference` class overrides the `equals()` method. So it inherits the `equals()` method from Object, which only considers two objects to be equal if they are the same object.

Comment: Do you have any idea on overriding equals? How would we implement it?

Comment: I don't know enough about weak references to know if it's a good idea or not to subclass it and override equals() or not. I guess it wouldn't be a good idea, else it would be done in WeakReference directly. Loop over the list to find the one you're looking for, and remove it. That's what the list does anyway when remove() is called.

Comment: Maybe i can return the weakrefence to the owner itself when it tries to add itself to this list? So it can directly use that reference to remove itself?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious option is looping along the list, and compare the target objet with the referent of every Reference (`owner.equals(reference.get())` or `owner == reference.get()` if what you are checking is that both variables point to the very same object).